# How do i set the xpath right for the "label for"

Tags: python, selenium

I'm experimenting with selenium in python, but I do not have experience using it.  I am trying to use XPath to locate the button which has the code below (source).thanks.

I've tried using

```
size = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@label for = 'skuAndSize__22833586:8']").click()
```

source:

```
<label for="skuAndSize__22833586:8" tabindex="-1" class="css-ya7s8z css-15ar8n4">UK 7</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

The element is a label, it's attribute is "for", so this is the correct selection:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@for='skuAndSize__22833586:8']").click()
```

Hope it helps.